# Value not found in data frame in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Original data frame has all 3 columns i.e. `name`, `description` and `specialties` columns in it.

I want to input a company name, compare its specialties with all other companies' specialties and during comparison whenever I found a match I want to print and save all the details of the found match.

```
df_descrip = df_original[['name', 'description']]
df_spec  = df_original[['name','specialties']]
INPUT ='TOTAL'
all_names = df_original['name']
df_original = df_original.set_index('name', drop = False)
columns = df_original.columns
for index, row in df_original.iterrows():
    if row['name'] == INPUT:
        specialties_input = df_original.loc[INPUT,'specialties']
        print('INPUT SPECIALTIES: ', specialties_input)

for spec in specialties_input:
    for item in df_spec['specialties']:
        if spec in item:
            # here I want to display details of a match
```

NOTE: Suppose If I input company name 'TOTAL' and it has 5 specialties (s1,s2,s3,s4,s5) I will compare all of them with the specialties of all companies in my data frame. let's say I find a match i-e s3 in specialties, how can I get the name of the matched company ?

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with expected output?

Comment: kindly check the edit and help if you can. 
i have added images of sample data thats not actual data.

Comment: hmmm, so check [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and create samples from actual data.

Comment: Please provide a script with data embedded so that people are able to run your script. Nobody will write by hand data from those images: see [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you've provided is not very clean or replicable, so I've created sample data here.

Assuming you can split specialties by `','`, it's simpler to work with lists and sets than with strings for this kind on analysis.

```
# Sample Data
df = pd.DataFrame({'description': ['d1', 'd2', 'd3'], 
                   'specialties': ['s1,s2,s3', 's3,s4,s5,s6', 's5,s6,s7']}, 
                  index=['name1', 'name2', 'name3'])

# Sample Input
name_lookup = 'name3'

tgt_set = set(df.loc[name_lookup, 'specialties'].split(','))
intersection = df['specialties'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: tgt_set.intersection(x))
match = intersection != set() # Remove companies with 0 matches

# Output:

intersection[match] # will deliver the specialties they have in common

df[match] # will return the data only on the ones that have at lest one specialty in common
```

Comment: hi, can you help a lil bit more ? I want to get only 5 names with highest number of matches in intersection. how would I do that

Comment: Adding something like this will give you the top 5 names intersection.apply(len).sort_values().tail(5).index

Comment: I want a dataframe in result having entries with maximum matches